# iphone screensaver (with clock)

Tags: iphone, screensaver, clock

Could I create an iPhone app that replaces/modifies the default clock screen saver and show something else instead (e.g. my own special clock or whatever)?

How do I go about doing that? I'd appreciate a link to a tutorial on the subject, or to example code that does something like this.

(disclaimer: total iPhone dev noob here)

Comment: I doubt very much you'd be given access to that - an app that runs as a screen saver could have the potential to gobble up lots of battery power with the user even knowing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to override any of the functionality on the existing apps/features on the iPhone, including the screen that is shown when the phone is locked.  You could write an app that mimicked that functionality when launched, but I don't think that's what you're looking to do.

Comment: so wait, can't even change the background image every minute or so even?

Comment: man, iphone blows. now I'm reading online that I'd have to jailbreak the device in order to do this (or even to use my own ringtones). jeez.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a violation of apples UI guidelines and there is a good chance it would not be accepted to the app store.